# How to create a Kconfig file

Tags: kernel

So i have a hello world module and a Makefile for it. I want the module to be shown in the make menuconfig window! How do i do that? By creating a new Kconfig file or something? If so, how to create a new Kconfig file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First create a "Kconfig" file in the same directory and edit the file as follows:

ex:

```
 menu "Networking"
 config NET
 tristate "my network driver" # --> this line gives the desc of the ko.
 depends on <ARCH>
 default y if <ARCH>
 help
   <Text displayed when help is selected for your driver>.
```

You can also create multi level menus, for more details refer to [Kconfig](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/kbuild/kconfig-language.txt)